# Which version of Sqoop work with Hadoop 0.20.2?

Tags: hadoop, version, sqoop

Does Sqoop 2 work with Hadoop 0.20.2?

What version of sqoop is best to download?

1.4.2 or 1.99.1 ?

Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop have currently two main branches. Sqoop 1 is older fully functional and mature project supporting Hadoop 0.20, 1.x, 0.23 and 2.0.x You can download the bits from [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.4/). Please make sure that you download file ending with "_hadoop-0.20", otherwise you will be getting weird exceptions.

Second branch is Sqoop2 which is redesign of the project. There is available first cut with version 1.99.3. This branch is supporting only Hadoop 1.x and 2.x and can be downloaded from [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.99.3/). Again you need to make sure to download version that matches your hadoop distribution. There is a probability that the build for Hadoop 1.x will be working on 0.20.2 as well as those versions are not that different, however nobody has verified that.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking same way but couldn't find info anywhere