# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, hadoop, import, sqoop

I am using hadoop 1.0.3 and sqoop 1.4.6. I am trying to import a table from MySQL to hdfs. I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected
    at org.apache.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:65)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to sqoop being compiled on hadoop 1.x, 
you can download sqoop compiled on hadoop 2.x on the sqoop site,
goto link - releases / sqoop 1 
should look something like this,

sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-1.0.0.tar.gz
sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha.tar.gz
get the sqoop or hadoop2.x should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be due to versions. Also please give the command details you have used.

Issue can be due to sqoop/sqoop2. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269950/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interfa).
Or in general, due to different versions of sqoop and haddop. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269950/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interfa)

General compatibility for sqoop and haddop versions info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886353/which-version-of-sqoop-work-with-hadoop-0-20-2)

Comment: thanks Ramzy but I can not solve this issue.I am installing a new version:hadoop 2.7.1 and sqoop 1.4.6